# Is TabbedArea deprecated in React-Bootstrap?

Tags: react-bootstrap

I've upgraded to react-bootstrap 0.28.1 and React 0.14.3

Since this change ReactBootstrap TabbedArea and TabPane no longer works. When we build our project (using web pack) TabbedArea is undefined.

It seems that replacing it with Tabs and Tab works.

Is TabbedArea known to be no longer supported?

Answer (score 0):

yes. Use Tabs instead. With thanks to the react-bootstrap team:

https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1565